# RNTester -> A problem occurred evaluating project :ReactAndroid

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to install the RNTester, using the facebook/react-native tutorial [ https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/RNTester ] but when I executing "./gradlew :RNTester:android:app:installDebug" show me an error.

```
This is for the Ubuntu 19.04, running Android Studio 3.5 and java openjdk version "1.8.0_222"

** build.gradle File**

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

** error executing ./gradlew :RNTester:android:app:installDebug **

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/g/projects/react-native/react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle' line: 220

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ReactAndroid'.
> extensionSupplier.get()!!.compileSdkVersion must not be null

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':ReactAndroid'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing [fixing commit from the React Native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7c8e266e390de71ce39233b53a369b2c5e8a1c14):

> It is happening because **buildReactNdkLib** task was created and configured eagerly. So this PR changes some tasks to be configured lazily, and reads values from **android** when ready. Also remove ANDROID_NDK variable check because android gradle plugin doing it automatically.

The problem has been solved yesterday on `react-native#master`. Try pulling in the latest changes and building RNTester then!